# Smallest Algebra with 2 events?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

**21/03/2022: The question remains Unsolved**

According to wikipedia:

> A field of sets is a mathematical structure consisting of a pair
> ${\displaystyle (X,{\mathcal {F}})} $ consisting of a set  $X $ and a
> family  $ {\mathcal {F}}$ of subsets of  $X $ called an algebra over
> $X $ that contains the empty set as an element, and is closed under
> the operations of taking complements in  $X$, finite unions, and
> finite intersections.

My professor asked:

> what is the smallest sigma algebra that contains two events $A, B$

My answer is much smaller than the one suggested by my professor thus is wrong, what did I do wrong?

I suggested:

$A, B, A \cup B, \emptyset $

over $2^{A \cup B}$

It's clear that according to the definition it's algebra.

Comment: Algebra is also closed under finite intersections. Your sets are not guaranteed to be disjoint

Comment: not according to wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

A sigma algebra must also be closed under complements, hence must contain $X\setminus A$. In general, $X\setminus A$ is not among your sets.

---

Then again, the problem statement (as presented here) is perhaps a bit ambiguous: Note that for any non-empty set $X$, the set $\{\emptyset,X\}$ is a sigma algebra over $X$ and contains two events. So if we are allowed to **pick** $A,B$ as $A=\emptyset$ and $B=X$, this is a rather small sigma algebra with the desired property. If we are not even required to make $A,B$ distinct, we can go even further ...

Comment: Hi, I think you are wrong... I said it's algebra over $2^{A \cup B}$ so yes it's closed under complementary as ${A \cup B}$ \ $A=A^c=B$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a $\sigma$ Algebra is also closed under complementary, so for example you're missing $A^c, B^c$ union and intersection of them. Try adding all of this complementary sets.

Comment: Hi, I think you are wrong... I said it's algebra over $2^{A \cup B}$ so yes it's closed under complementary as ${A \cup B}$ \ $A=A^c=B$

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the definition of an algebra over a particular set, in this case I think that you're missing the events $A \cap B$ and similar

Comment: That's not correct, $A^c$ is $B$ and $B^c$ is $A$. so $A intersection B$= Empty Set

Comment: @Dan No $A^c = B - A ≠ B $ in fact you're assertion is right iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$. And if could be useful instead of intersection and Empty set you could use \cap and \emptyset in between two '$' symbols